# Spring form does nothing

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to update user settings info. When I hit submit, nothing happens.

Here is my settings controller

```
@Secured({ "ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN" })
@RequestMapping(value = "/settings**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView settings() {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String userName = auth.getName();
    User userInfo = userDAO.getUserInfo(userName);
    Settings settings = userDAO.getSettingsInfo(userInfo.getDetails().getMacAddress());
    List<Plugs> plugs = userInfo.getDetails().getPlugs();
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("settings", settings);
    model.addObject("plugs", plugs.get(plugs.size() - 1));
    return model;
}

@Secured({ "ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN" })
@RequestMapping(value = "/settings", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView settings(@Valid @ModelAttribute("settings") Settings settings, BindingResult result) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String userName = auth.getName();
    User userInfo = userDAO.getUserInfo(userName);
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        model.setViewName("welcome");
    } else {
        model.setViewName("settings");
        userDAO.updateSettings(userInfo);
    }

    return model;
}
```

JSP form

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="settings" commandName="settings">
```

And here is my submit button

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" name ="submit">
```

How do I get my form to do anything? It supposed to update the user details in a MySQL database. If you want more code posted, I'll add it.

Comment: What does "does nothing" mean? Is the model empty? do you get a status code - other than 200 - after submit? Does the submit work at all?

Comment: @fateddy "does nothing" means it literally does nothing. The submit button doesn't do anything. No status code or anything.

Comment: So pressing the submit button does NOT initiate the post request? Is the submit button inside the `<form>`?

Comment: If you open your browser in debug mode, are you seeing a POST?

Comment: Ah I'm stupid. I had a logout form inside my submit form which caused to submit form to not do anything

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to add action attribute in form tag as below?

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="settings" commandName="settings" action="/settings">
```

if your Springframework DispatcherServlet servlet mapping's url pattern is other than "/" in web.xml, please append that pattern before "/settings" as below:

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="settings" commandName="settings" action="{url pattern}/settings">
```

Comment: can you please share your web.xml and Spring Web configuration file xml?